# How do I deploy my local SQL server database to google cloud?

Tags: .net, sql-server, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, entity-framework-core

I deployed my .NET 5 application to google cloud and it's working accordingly. My application is divided in microservices, and in the context of the question, I have 6 microservices which possess databases (all use SQL Server and we manage them through SSMS).

We tested locally and everything seems to work just fine. We use the local SQL Server and the associated connection string in each microservice. We executed the commands to add the migrations and to update the database (tables) with our code first approach.
Altough we read some documentation, there are a lot of nuances that we are not aware and since this is our first time making this, I would like some guidance on how to achieve what we have locally, but in the GCP.

In other words, how can we make our GCP deployed microservices use our GCP SQL Server instance? Do we only need one instance to all the databases? How are the connection strings configured? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Did you have a look to Cloud SQL documentation?

Comment: We did. Our stress is to connect a microservice to the GCP DB instance and vice versa. We enabled private IP's. We connected to the GCP instance through SSMS. But how microservices can't reach the DB. This is our biggest problem.

Comment: If you use private IP, you have to use the serverless VPC connector to bridge the serverless world where live your microservices and your VPC where the Cloud SQL instance is connected. And I don't know the SSMS...

Comment: Can you state  which infrastructure(App Engine, Cloud Run, GKE etc.) you are using to deploy your application in GCP? Also can you make it clear whether the SQL Server instances are Local or GCP Cloud SQL instances?